# Jquery refresh div block one time to show php session

Tags: jquery, refresh, php

How could I refresh div with id which is contain PHP session?

my JQ ajax call:

```
$('#btn_1').click(function(){
    var parameters = $('#booking_form').serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: baseurl + 'site/process',
        type: 'POST',
        data: parameters,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(output_str){
            if(output_str == "false"){
                $('#result_msg').html("please select one");

            }else{
                $('#result').html(output_str);
                $('#loaddiv').load();

            }
        }
    });
});
```

here is where I wanna to reload after ajax callback:

```
<p>
<div id="result" style="color:#606;"></div>
</p>

<div id="loaddiv">
    <p><?php echo $selected; ?></p>
    <p><?php echo $sum_charges; ?></p>
</div>
```

`$selected` and `$sum_charges` is a php session that is stored during the process, the session would only show up in page when I refresh it manually, how could I make the session show immediately when the result callback to page?

Thanks!!

**Edit:**

I using codeigniter (still new in CI) in my process, here is part of my controller for this process:

```
public function process(){
    $confTypes = $this->input->post('cType');
    $user_email = $this->input->post('user_email');
    $output_str = NULL;
    $conf_charge_total = 0;

    if(!empty($confTypes)){

        foreach($confTypes as $confType){
            $explode_value = explode(",", $confType);

            $conf_type = $explode_value[0];
            $conf_charge = $explode_value[1];

            $conf_charge_total += $conf_charge; //sum up checked values

            $output_str .= $conf_type.":".$conf_charge.",";
            /*$output_str = array(
                    'selected' => $conf_type.','.$conf_charge,
                    'email' => $user_email,
                    'sum' => $conf_charge_total,
                    'flag' => 'true'
                );*/
            $this->session->set_userdata('selected', $output_str);

        }

        $output_str .= $conf_charge_total;

        $this->session->set_userdata('sum_charges', $conf_charge_total);

    }else{
        $output_str = "false";
    }

    echo json_encode($output_str);
}
```

Comment: do you have your js script on the same page... or your are maintaining it in seperate js file ??

Comment: As I understand you want to update `div#loaddiv` after processing `baseurl + 'site/process'` page.

Comment: @bipen, my .js file is in separate.

Comment: @Rohan Kumar, yes that is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

if your js script is in the same page you can do..

```
success: function(output_str){
        if(output_str == "false"){
            $('#result_msg').html("please select one");

        }else{
            $('#result').html(output_str);
            var divContent="<p><?php echo $selected; ?></p><p><?php echo $sum_charges; ?></p>"; //this will echo the latest session variable...
              $('#loaddiv').html(divContent);

        }
    }
```

**updated**

send your session variable as json

**PHP**

```
 echo json_encode(array('selected'=>$selected,'sum_charges'=>$sum_charges,'output_str'=>'yourStr'));
```

**JQUERY**

```
success: function(output_str){
        if(output_str == "false"){
            $('#result_msg').html("please select one");

        }else{
            $('#result').html(output_str.output_str);
            var dinContent="<p>"+output_str.selected+"</p><p>"+output_str.sum_charges+"</p>"; //this will echo the latest session variable...
              $('#loaddiv').html(dinContent);

        }
    }
```

Comment: other workaround is to send the session variables as json from the server and displaying it...

Answer (score 0):

The ajax calling page returns `json` as you used `dataType: 'json'`, then the called page should return a `json formatted string` like

`echo json_encode(array("selected"=>"abc","sum_charges"=>123));`

In your `ajax function` change the success function like:

```
success: function(output_str){
    if(output_str == "false"){
        $('#result_msg').html("please select one");

    }else{
        $('#result').html(output_str);
        var str="<p>"+output_str.selected+"</p><p>"+output_str.sum_charges+"</p>";
        $('#loaddiv').html(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have try your changed and the loaddiv still need to refresh the page another one time to show the session out.

Comment: @conmen When the page is first loaded it will show the `default session values` by variables `$selected` and `$sum_charges`, then you click on a button these values should be changed according to `baseurl + 'site/process'` page, Right?

Comment: yes, i want these values in session is for further processing, that why I can't just output by `output_str.selected`.

Comment: Ok the above will only show the updated values, you want to store these values in `session` then the page `site/process` will do this by setting `session variable` like `$_SESSION['selected']` etc, also for further use you can assign this value in `$selected` variable or by direct use `$_SESSION['$selected']`.